# Displaying a list from a controller on a Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout, list, pagereference

I am trying to collect all of the cases that the user saves and display them in a queue at the top right of the page so they can tell which cases have already been completed. I have put a method together that should collect the data needed, I need to know how to display this data on the Visualforce page. This is the code I have so far.

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case_Note__c" recordSetVar="MassAddCaseNotes" tabStyle="Case_Note__c" extensions="MassAddCaseNotes">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Mass Add Case Notes" />  
<apex:form>

<apex:pageBlock title="Case Notes" >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSave" immediate="false" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveandclose}" value="Save and Close" status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSaveClose" immediate="false" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>                                        
    <apex:actionStatus layout="block" startText="Saving notes. . . " stopText="" id="retrieveSaveStatus" startStyle="color:green; font-style:italic" stopStyle="color:black;"/>

    <apex:pageMessages showDetail="false" />
    <br/> 
    <apex:outputText value="Enter Notes to submit to cases then select cases the notes will be submitted to." style="font-style:italic" /><br/>             
    <br/>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Your Notes " columns="1">
    <apex:outputLabel for="CaseNote"> </apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputField style="width:300px;height:100px;" value="{!Case_Notes.Note__c}" id="CaseNote"  />
</apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="margin-bottom: 15px;"> 
                   <apex:outputLabel for="Date">Date: </apex:outputLabel>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!Case_Notes.Date__c}" id="Date" />

                    <apex:outputLabel for="contactFilter">Contact: </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!filterCase.ContactId}" id="contactFilter" />

                    <apex:commandButton action="{!selectCases}" value="Filter" />
            </apex:panelGrid>

                <div style="float:right; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" value="Previous Page" rendered="{!hasPrevious}" />
                <apex:outputLabel value="Previous Page" style="color: gray" rendered="{!NOT(hasPrevious)}" />
                |
                <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" value="Next Page" rendered="{!hasNext}" />
                <apex:outputLabel value="Next Page" style="color: gray" rendered="{!NOT(hasNext)}" />
            </div>

     <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="case" >

      <apex:column >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selectedCases[case.Id]}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Case Number" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="CaseNumber" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.CaseNumber}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Record Type" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="RecordType.Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.RecordType.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Contact" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="Contact.Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.Contact.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Account" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="Account.Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.Account.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Date Opened" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="Opened_Date__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.Opened_Date__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Program Location Assignment" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="Program_Location_Assignment__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.Program_Location_Assignment__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Referring Agency" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="Referring_Agency__r.Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.Referring_Agency__r.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
           </apex:PageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>      
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class**

```
public class MassAddCaseNotes {

public Case_Note__c Case_Notes {get; set;}
    public List<Case> cases                         {get; private set;}
    public Map<Id, Boolean> selectedCases           {get; set;}
    public Case filterCase                          {get; set;}    
    public String sortField                         {get; set;}
    public boolean direction                        {get; set;}

    private final String selectCasesQuery = 'SELECT Id, CaseNumber, RecordType.Name, Contact.Name, Account.Name, Opened_Date__c, ClosedDate, Program_Location_Assignment__c, Referring_Agency__r.Name ' +
                                            'FROM Case ' +
                                            'WHERE Status=\'Open\' AND RecordTypeId IN (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = \'Case\' AND IsActive = true)';
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController allCases {get; set;}

    public MassAddCaseNotes (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) 
    {
        Case_Notes = new Case_Note__c(); 
        filterCase = new Case();

        direction = true;
        selectCases();
        direction = false;
    }

    public void selectCases() {
        if (sortField == null) sortField = 'CaseNumber';
        String filter = '';
        if (filterCase.RecordTypeId != null) filter += ' AND RecordTypeId = \'' + filterCase.RecordTypeId + '\'';
        if (filterCase.ContactId != null) filter += ' AND ContactId = \'' + filterCase.ContactId + '\'';
        if (filterCase.AccountId != null) filter += ' AND AccountId = \'' + filterCase.AccountId + '\'';

        allCases = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(selectCasesQuery + filter +  ' ORDER BY ' + sortField + (direction ? ' ASC' : ' DESC')));
        allCases.setPageSize(200);
        updateCases();
    }

    public void sortCases() {
        direction = !direction;
        selectCases();
    }

    public Boolean hasPrevious {get {return allCases.getHasPrevious();}}
    public Boolean hasNext {get {return allCases.getHasNext();}}

    public void previous() {
        allCases.previous();
        updateCases();
    }

    public void next() {
        allCases.next();
        updateCases();
    }

    private void updateCases() {
        cases = allCases.getRecords();
        selectedCases = new Map<Id, Boolean>();
        for (Case c : cases) {
            selectedCases.put(c.Id, false);
        }
    }

    public void addtoqueue()
    {
        List<Case_Note__c> queue = new List<Case_Note__c>();

        for (Case c : cases) {
            if (selectedCases.get(c.Id)) {
                Case_Note__c items = new Case_Note__c(
                    Case__c = c.Id,
                    Date__c = Case_Notes.Date__c,
                    Contact_Name__c = Case_Notes.Contact_Name__c
                );               
                queue.add(items);
            }
        }
    }

    public PageReference save() 
    {
        List<Case_Note__c> note = new List<Case_Note__c>();
        for (Case c : cases) {
            if (selectedCases.get(c.Id)) {
                Case_Note__c s = new Case_Note__c(
                    Case__c = c.Id,
                    Date__c = Case_Notes.Date__c,
                    Note__c = Case_Notes.Note__c
                );               
                note.add(s);
            }
        }
        insert note;        
        addtoqueue();

         return null;
    }

    public PageReference saveandclose() 
    {
        List<Case_Note__c> note = new List<Case_Note__c>();
        for (Case c : cases) {
            if (selectedCases.get(c.Id)) {
                Case_Note__c s = new Case_Note__c(
                    Case__c = c.Id,
                    Date__c = Case_Notes.Date__c,
                    Note__c = Case_Notes.Note__c
                );               

                note.add(s);
            }
        }
        insert note;  

        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/500/o');
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }
}
```

The list that I am trying to display on the visualforce page is the `addtoqueue` list.

Comment: are you trying to add the queue list? addtoQueue is a method that returns nothing,

Comment: My apologies, I did mean the queue list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the Queue list outside the addqueue method to the variable declaration area ( make it a public variable) below

```
public boolean direction                        {get; set;}
```

Add

```
public List<Case_Note__c> queue {get;set;}
```

Inside MassAddCaseNotes (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) add

```
queue = new List<case_Note__c>();
```

Page:

Below the `</apex:pageblocktable>` add

```
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!addtoqueue}" var="que">
<apex:column headervalue="Casenote Id" value="{!que.Id}"/>
<apex:column headervalue="Casenote date" value="{!que.date__c}"/>
<apex:column headervalue="Casenote NAme" value="{!que.Name__c}"/>
</apex:pageblocktable>
```